# Como actualizar base de datos en la carpeta assets

Tags: android, sqlite

soy nuevo en Android Studio, tengo una aplicacion que muestra una lista de nombres desde una base de datos, todo funciona bien excepto que no detecta los cambios de la base de datos, el archivo miembros.db se reemplaza correctamente por el nuevo en el directorio assets, pero al correr la aplicacion los datos continuan igual.

La unica forma que actualice es desinstalando la app y volverla a instalar, mi pregunta es... hay alguna otra forma que el sistema detecte que miembros.db cambió sin necesidad de desinstalar/instalar la app?

muchas gracias

Comment: ¿Estás usando Sqlite para manejar tu base de datos?

Comment: si, utilizo SQLite